# Laravel model - uncast specific column

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel table with a column I've defined like this in the migration:

```
$table->json('json');
```

And in the model, I cast it to an array:

```
protected $casts = [
    'json' => 'array'
];
```

This works perfectly the majority of the time I need it, but there's one api call I'm making where I actually want my collection of that Model to give me the raw string rather than casting it to the array.

So, assuming my model is called Model, my api call looks like this:

```
$systemModels = Model::whereNull('user_id')->get();
$userModels = Model::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();

return response()->json([
        'user_models' => $userModels->toArray(),
        'system_models' => $systemModels->toArray()
    ]);
```

This is where I'd like the 'json' column of my Model to be rendered as a string rather than cast to an array. Is there a reliable way to do that?

Comment: I accept that one possibility is that I remove the cast from the model and use `json_decode` in the places where I do need it as an array, but I'm just not sure if Laravel has facilities to do what I'm asking here, I'd like to know.

Comment: I think you could set a mutator instead. One that converts the field to an array. If Laravel sets the attributes before dealing with the cast array, then maybe you can get away with defining a getter to get the raw string...

Comment: So you want the api to return `{"json": "[1, 2]"}` rather than `{"json": [1, 2]}`? I would be very annoyed by your api tbh.

Comment: @Jerodev yes! But the use case of my api, it makes sense to return it like that at this particular endpoint. You wouldn't be annoyed because you'd never need to access it as an object, as a consumer of my api. You'd only ever want to change the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your model you can define a custom attribute which is added when the model is serialized:

```
class YourModel extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['json_raw'];

    public function getJsonRawAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['json'];
        // or return json_encode($this->attributes['json']);
    }
}
```

And then when doing the `toArray()` you can do `$userModels->makeHidden('json')->toArray();` to remove the casted field you do not want.

Comment: Tis will still include the casted `json` property in the array.

Comment: @Jerodev it won't when you do `makeHidden('json')` like I said.

Comment: The 'json' field would still show up, but just not casted to array?

Comment: @TKoL you will have a new field `json_raw` and if you want to remove the casted field use `$model->makeHidden('json')->toArray()`.